# Does the host use full resources while VM is inactive?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I have read that the ram that has been given to the VM is occupied only when the VM is active.

I just installed in VirtualBox the Windows 10 and when I turned it off, I decided to check on Task manager of the host if all the initial Cores the laptop has are back.
Strangely it appears that the Cores given to the VM are not available fully.

The laptop has 8 cores and 4 have been given to the VM.

On the picture displays that only 4 are available:
[image: Picture]

This mentions 8 of which 4 are selected for the VM.

[image: pic]

Comment: What makes you think the AMD Ryzen 5 3500U has 8 cores? It has 4, with 8 HT [Hyper Threading] - https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-5-3500u

Comment: @Tetsujin see the edit with the new image

Comment: …which is a reflection of the logical cores, not physical.

Comment: If the virtual machines have been powered off (and not suspended), then no host resources go to virtual machines - the resources all stay with the host machine.

Comment: thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that the ram that has been given to the VM is occupied
> only when the VM is active.

That is correct. If a virtual machine has been powered off (and not suspended or otherwise on), then all Memory and Processors revert to and stay with the host machine.

You can suspend a guest with the virtual app (VMware or Virtual Box) and in this case, resources also stay only with the host machine.